# Make ArcMap label using the first letter from each word in an attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, labeling, python-parser

How do I create labels using the first letter of each word from a specific attribute, preferably using Python as the parser?

For example, the attribute name is Common_Name and the values are eastern white pine, balsam fir, plus many others. Cases may be mixed (e.g. some might be Eastern White Pine or Balsam fir), but I'd like the labels to be all capitols, like EWP and BF, respectively.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose Python parser, check Advanced checkbox and:

```
def FindLabel ( [FIELD] ):
  input = [FIELD]  
  output = ""
  for i in input.upper().split():
    output += i[0]  
  return output
```

Change FIELD to the name of your field

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had found code using `split`but wasn't sure how to get it into the labeling function properly.

Comment: @MAHE nice! Next time add your code attempt to your question and it will not be closed

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [Update Cursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) approach:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\path\to\your\geodb.gdb\featureclass'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['trees', 'trees_abbr']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = ''.join(row[0].upper() for row in row[0].split(' ')) 
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: this is also good because the new field can be used for other things as well.